# How to display a message in a pop up window

Tags: javascript, function, popup

I have a pop up window function where when a button is clicked the window does pop up. Now the pop up window does not display anything, for a test I want the pop up window to display the word "Session". But I don't know how to do this.

Am I supposed to write the word "Session" in another page and link to that page or is it possible to write the word "Session" on the same page and link it to that section of the page?

I want the latter to happen but I don't know how to do it.

Below is my code:

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Create a Session</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                    function openSessionPopup (session) {
 window.open(session,
 'window',
 'width=500,height=500,scrollbars=yes,status=no');
 }

</script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="create_session.php" method="post" name="sessionform">
<p><input class="questionBtn" type="button" value="Prepare Questions" name="prequestion" onClick="openSessionPopup(this.href); return false"  /></p>      
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: why not just use `javascript:alert('your text here')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var win = window.open("about:blank", null, "width=400,height=300");
var doc = win.document;
doc.open("text/html");
doc.write("Session");
doc.close();
```

**[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/wVwQY/) on JSFiddle.**

Alternatively, you can create a new page with the content you want and open that:

```
window.open("my-new-page.html", null, "width=400,height=300");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the word session into the popup.. be sure to use " before and after since it's string... like this window.open("session", 'window', ...

" or ' will do the job either way.

Answer (score 0):

Your popup typically displays another page when it appears. It is this other page that will have the content you want displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This code would never work. When you pass in `this.href`, the `this` refers to the input element on which you've clicked. Input elements do not have an 'href' attribute, so you're passing in an undefined value.

Answer (score 0):

First parameter in `windows.open` function is URL. So when you passed an empty value it opened the window with url `about:blank` (empty page).

If you want open url http://example.com/ in popup window you must use your function as:
`openSessionPopup('http://example.com/');`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the href as the argument for the "session" parameter. You see this works by putting this code into a file called "question.html" and testing out the button.

Replace the href with the page you want to display.

`onClick="openSessionPopup('question.html'); return false"`